# iOS: several push providers for one application

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I'm just wondering if it's possible to receive push notifications from both Urban Airship and Parse (for example) within just one iOS application.

If so, can I distinguish notifications from different providers if I don't use custom payloads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create multiple apns certificates for the same app in the developer center, to send notification from different providers.

However you will have to use a custom payload to distinguish one provider from the other.